# Watson Assistant - UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to connect my NodeJS client application **running locally from within a corporate proxy** to Watson Assistant Service.

To set-up connection, I am using the following code.

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent("<proxyserver:port>");

var assistant = new AssistantV2({
  version: '2019-02-28',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator
     ({apikey: *<apikey here>*, httpsAgent}),
  url: 'https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api',
  disableSslVerification: true,
  httpsAgent,
});
```

But, I get the following error in console

```
Server running on port: 3100
{ Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at RequestWrapper.formatError (*<actual path hidden>*\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:208:21)
    at *<actual path hidden>*\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:196:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
  message: 'unable to get local issuer certificate',
  statusText: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
  body:
   'Response not received - no connection was made to the service.' }
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by your proxy performing TLS intercept.

You have several options:

1. set `strict-ssl=false`.
2. set `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=fullpath_to_certificates_file`

For the first method, you are disabling certificate validation. This might be OK in a controlled environment (your source code) but make sure you know what you are doing.

For the second method, ask your admin for the SSL root and intermediate certificates. Basically, you are telling your system to trust those certificates.